# Does simple-prefs has password type?

Tags: firefox-addon-sdk

I wanna allow user to configure connection settings to my service (username/password). [simple-prefs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/simple-prefs) perfectly fits my requirements except I didn't find `password` type. I don't wanna use `string` field to store password value. How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

There is no `password` type at the moment, all prefs are stored as clear text strings, ints, or booleans.

You may be able to use the [`sdk/password`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/passwords) module however.